# OpenGL rendering randomly changes?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Sorry for the specific problem, but I can't find any explanations for my problem. I'm almost certain it's a stupid mistake I'm overlooking.

I just want to draw a basic multicolor rectangle to the screen. It works fine, and I even got code for model-view-projection matrices to work. However, I found that when I try to re-assign the value of the uniform I use as an MVP matrix, the program will suddenly fail after rendering a few hundred times. Whereas the first few moments I have exactly what I want, after ~300 calls to the uniform-updating method, I get a completely different screen with a weird shape and colors I never asked for.

I tried to reduce my code to a minimum. My fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

My vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_MVP;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() {
    v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = u_MVP * a_Position;
}
```

And the Java that calls it:

```
package com.ulyssecarion.openglsandbox;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ulyssecarion.openglsandbox.util.ShaderHelper;
import com.ulyssecarion.openglsandbox.util.TextResourceReader;

public class OpenGLSandboxRenderer implements Renderer {
    private static final String TAG = "SandboxRenderer";

    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;

    private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT)
            * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

    private static final String U_MVP = "u_MVP";
    private static final String A_COLOR = "a_Color";
    private static final String A_POSITION = "a_Position";

    private float[] mvp;

    private float time;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private int uMVP;
    private int aColor;
    private int aPosition;

    private Context context;
    private int program;

    public OpenGLSandboxRenderer(Context context) {
        time = 0;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        setMVP(width, height);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVP, 1, false, mvp, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    }

    private static FloatBuffer toFB(float[] x) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(x.length
                * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer buffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        buffer.put(x);
        buffer.position(0);
        return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        uMVP = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MVP);
        aColor = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_COLOR);
        aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);

        Log.d(TAG, "MVP at: " + uMVP);

        setMVP(width, height);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVP, 1, false, mvp, 0);

        // @formatter:off
        float[] points = {
                 0.0f,  0.0f, 1, 1, 1, 
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0,
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 1, 
                 0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1, 0,
                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 1, 1,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0
        };
        // @formatter:on

        FloatBuffer pointData = toFB(points);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aPosition, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT,
                false, STRIDE, pointData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);

        pointData.position(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aColor, COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, false,
                STRIDE, pointData);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

        String vertexShaderSrc = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(
                context, R.raw.simple_vertex_shader);
        String fragmentShaderSrc = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(
                context, R.raw.simple_fragment_shader);
        int vertexShader = ShaderHelper.compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSrc);
        int fragmentShader = ShaderHelper
                .compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSrc);

        program = ShaderHelper.linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

        glUseProgram(program);
    }

    private void setMVP(int width, int height) {
        mvp = new float[16];

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mvp, 0);

        Log.d(TAG, "Setting MVP: " + time++);
    }
}
```

The `TextResourceReader` and `ShaderHelper` classes are boilerplate classes that I'm pretty sure work correctly.

Any ideas?

*Edit:*

Here's what it looks like normally:

[image]

*Edit #2*

This is what it looks like when it goes crazy:

[image]

another example:

[image]

(Sorry for the gigantic images)

Note: the result is not always what is shown above. Previously, it was generally resulting in a black screen.

Comment: *...the program will suddenly fail...* Is there a stack trace or an error message that you could provide?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner No stack trace or error; the displayed rectangle will instead be replaced by some random (changes every time it seems) shape that has some random color.

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't actually crash. Would it be possible to get a screenshot of the way it looks normally, and the way it looks afterwards?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner just did so.

Comment: Emulator's OpenGL ES 2.0 isn't stable (at least on Windows, may be Mac is better). You should really try a real device too.

Comment: Try checking errors after each GL call, also try getting locations of attributes and uniforms every frame, probably they are invalidated at some point.

Comment: @q______b The attribs and uniforms aren't changing, and glGetError always returns 0 (for the methods called by onDrawFrame).